# Contribute to different repos forked from same repo

Tags: git, github

I'm quite new to GitHub and git, and I'm trying to figure out how I can contribute to different forks of a repo when they have been forked from each other. This is how the structure of the forks look:

1. Repo_A (original repo)
2. Repo_B (forked from Repo_A)
3. My_repo (forked from Repo_B)

Even though Repo_B is forked from Repo_A, it has evolved and differs from Repo_A. I am mainly going to contribute to Repo_B, but there might be some lines of codes I would like to contribute to Repo_A. Is there a way to do this without making two accounts and fork each repo?

I've been searching for answers and looking at different solutions without any luck. This is what I have tried so far:

- Forking Repo_A, making a pull request, then removing Repo_A and
  forking Repo_B. This method works if the changes is being commited.
  If not, the pull request will be automatically closed when the repo
  is removed from my account. It also feels a bit tedious to having to remove the repo and fork it for each time.
- Making a branch in My_repo with the
  single file I want to edit. Then copying the code from Repo_A, making
  the changes and sending a pull request to Repo_A. The problem then is
  that the history doesn't seem to be includeded and all the code is
  considered new lines (even though I only changed some characters).

I think I'm onto something with making branches.  But is it for example possible to make a branch in My_repo that has a file from Repo_A? And is it even possible to be contributing to both Repo_A and Repo_B from the same account even though they have gone different ways in development?

Comment: If repo B is not kept up to date with repo A, then I think the only coherent way for you to contribute to repo A is to fork it yourself. That way, _you_ can update your fork of repo A, branch, edit and commit, and submit your pull request. (I do not at all see why "two accounts" would needed.)

Comment: @matt But if I fork repo_A I don't seem to be able to contribute to Repo_B since I have to remove it. I am unable to fork both repos since they are connected.

Comment: Really? Sorry, I had no idea that that was the case. You can't fork both an original and its existing fork? If that's true, I see why you'd be miffed.

Comment: @matt Yeah, if I try to fork Repo_A, when I already have forked Repo_B it just says "No more forks can be created. These forks already exist:" with Repo_B and My_repo listed.

Answer (score 1):

If repo B has drifted *sufficiently far* from repo A, the owners of repo B might consider severing the fork (by deleting their repo B, then creating a new "repo B2").  The definition of "sufficiently far" is one of taste and intent and of course that's a matter for the owners of B, so you're kind of stuck here.

What you *can* do instead is to add, to your own (e.g., on-laptop) clone of your repo C that is a fork of B that is a fork of A, *two* remotes:

```
git remote add upstream-b ssh://git@github.com/userB/repoB.git
git remote add upstream-a ssh://git@github.com/userA/repoA.git
```

You can now run `git fetch --all` or `git remote update` to fetch from *all* your remotes, so that you have updates to all your `upstream-b/*` and `upstream-a/*` remote-tracking names.  Then create appropriate branch names and do work.  When it's ready, use `git push` to create or update appropriate branch names in your GitHub fork.  (Note that you'll need two distinct names in your GitHub fork for "stuff intended for repo B" vs "stuff intended for repo A", even if repositories A and B use the same branch names in *their* GitHub repositories.  That means you can match *at most one* branch name.)

Unfortunately, there's no way for you to generate a GitHub pull request *on* repo A.  All you can do at this point is send email to the owners *of* A, saying that you have some commits for them, that they're available in your GitHub repository and/or by email, and so on.  In other words, you can fall back to the original Git model, used by Linus & Co and by the Git developers, of sending patches via email and/or fetching directly from each other's repositories.

It would be nice if GitHub would enable some method of delivering a PR to the "fork parent of your fork parent".  That would solve the issue in the preceding paragraph.  Whether the GitHub folks would see some value in this is another question (though I suspect they would), and how difficult it would be for them to implement is yet another (though I suspect it would actually be pretty easy *except* for figuring out how to label and describe it all).